# React navigation bottom tab height iphone X and others (with and without tail)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image: without tail]
[image: with tail]

When I set the height of bottom tab style and tab style, the height of all device on ios changes. Which means that if the device do not have the tail bar, it will still have the same height as the one with safeareaview. I would like to make like this: if our device do not have the safeareaview, it will not have a white space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
use useSafeArea,

```
import { useSafeArea } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
const insets = useSafeArea();


style: {
    height: 55 + insets.bottom
},
tabStyle: {
  height: 55
}
```